# Media Gallery doesn't show (using WP-Read Only)

Tags: uploads, media

I've created a page and added a media gallery to it, but the media gallery doesn't display.

I think it may be related to my using [WP Read-Only](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wpro/), which stores all my images on S3 (because I'm on Heroku).  WP-Read Only doesn't run into any identifiable issues-- I can upload and crop just fine.  So maybe it's not the cause of the media gallery not showing.

Here's the shortcode output: `[gallery ids="54,55"]`

Here's the HTML in the content div on the media page:

```
<div id="content" role="main">                  
    <article id="post-29" class="post-29 page type-page status-publish hentry">
        <header class="entry-header">
            <h1 class="entry-title">Media</h1>
        </header>

        <div class="entry-content">

                    </div><!-- .entry-content -->
        <footer class="entry-meta">
                    </footer><!-- .entry-meta -->
    </article><!-- #post -->

   <div id="comments" class="comments-area">                            
   </div><!-- #comments .comments-area -->          
</div>
```

I'm using WordPress 3.5.2.  The only plugin other than WP Read-Only I have installed is Akismet.

**Update:** I dug into the `gallery_shortcode` function in wp_includes/media.php, and the issue is that `get_posts( array('include' => $include, 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order' => $order, 'orderby' => $orderby) );`  is returning an empty array so it returns nothing:

```
if ( empty($attachments) )
    return '';
```

Comment: What's the shortcode output?

Comment: (added to question) (also added the html it produces)

Comment: So gallery shortcode produce nothing. afaik this happens only in 2 cases: when there is function that hooks into 'post_gallery' filter and output something != '' but not visible (like a blank space) but this is a rarely case or, more frequently, when the query for attachments fails. Query is something like `get_posts(array('include'=>'50,55', 'post_status'=>'inherit','post_type'=>'attachment','post_mime_type'=>'image')` can you find something that can make it fails on your wp installation?

Comment: Sorry what do you want me to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue.  I'm using Postgres_SQL cus I'm on Heroku, but that doesn't play nicely with Wordpress.  Here's the problem query:

`SELECT wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts WHERE 1=1 AND wp_posts.ID IN (8,9)...`

It caused the error described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14132471/378622